# Are there any Email apps that render HTML emails?

Tags: email

Are there any email apps on the Market that can render HTML emails instead of just displaying the text of the email?  I know the GMail app can, but I want one that I can use to view HTML emails from my non-GMail accounts.

Comment: Update: To further clarify what I am looking for, I want to see the HTML email in its native form, not as plain text or HTML code. The GMail app can do that, but none of the other email apps I have found can do it.

Comment: Per my answer below, the the default "Mail" application built into Android supports HTML emails. I tested and verified and can send you a screenshot of my phone if necessary. If it doesn't work for you then something is converting it to text, but unless I'm missing something the Mail application does not do this by default. Please update your original post with more information, such as what email system you are using and with what settings. For example I am using the Mail client connected to Exchange.

Comment: I'm suspecting your email server's configuration could be faulty, and is sending a HTML email with text MIME. Can you try using your email apps using gmail or hotmail POP/IMAP server? (hotmail's html emails renders fine in mine)

Answer (score 3):

Mail app that comes on all Android phones can accept HTML emails, I just tested it. Go to Settings > Accounts & Sync > Add account and then add your other email accounts. Once added and sync'd you should be able to view them by going to your apps screen and scrolling to mail.

Comment: I am not talking about accepting HTML emails.  I am talking about the ability to actually render the HTML in the email.  I can already read HTML emails on my phone, but what I want to do is see the rendering of the HTML when I view the email.

Comment: Viewing HTML = Rendering HTML. Those terms are synonymous. Are you talking about viewing the HTML source? If not, then "Webs" is right--the stock e-mail apps show/render HTML e-mails perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes, I think we may need more clarification about what you want to do penti. UPDATE: Another thought, if all you see when you view an email is text, then you are not actually viewing the email in it's native HTML form. If you can view the HTML form of an email then you are viewing it as an HTML email. For example in Outlook you can convert emails to text only email, then HTML will not be supported with that email.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying happens by default in all of the email apps I have tried.  The HTML code of the email or just the text of the email is displayed.  I want to view the email in its native HTML form.  That is what the GMail app can do.

Comment: Can you please edit your question with this clarification?

Answer (score 3):

Go to app's menu > *More > Settings > Send and receive* > set mail size limit to *No limit*.

Enabling *No limit* will allow the inbuilt email app to render the HTML in emails. This does not work for exchange account however, but it does fix the text issue on all POP and IMAP email accounts.

Answer (score 2):

The native exchange client can't display HTML email if you use exchange server 2003.  The client "touchdown" (from the market) can.  This is a known bug.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting a similar problem here on an SGS with 2.3.3

The problem is that html emails are rendered as text (hence showing the html source) rather than rendered as html as the email is intended.

I have tried this with email (the default app), and also tried touchdown and k9 mail.

In my case, neither email nor touchdown rendered them properly, but k9 mail did.  This is a shame for me as email has a nice logo adjustment to show new mail, and integrates a little  better into things like the social hub.

I suspect that the problem is related to what is produced by my exchange type server, which is actually zimbra.  I'm sure your mileage would vary depending on your exchange version etc.